# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: exception, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm building this WP7 app that uses a video game API to get the statistics of someone's character (just to help learn silverlight). It grabs the players details from the web service and stores them on isolated storage on the phone to relieve strain from the server.

Originally I had a class which had both the cache writing and reading function, but now i've had to seperate it out into two seperate classes. The cache writing class doesn't matter at the moment, just the cache reading class.

On line 7, it throws an exception saying "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.", but only during the second time it instantiates the class. I've done some checking with debug and it says the file definately exists, but it stops after the second using clause.

Can anyone help me with this please? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

```
public class CacheReader
{
    public PlayerData GetPlayerData(string gamertagIn)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile CachedReachData = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = CachedReachData.OpenFile(gamertagIn + ".xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Data Retrieved from cache");
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlayerData));
                PlayerData loadedPlayer = (PlayerData)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                return loadedPlayer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[EDIT 1]**
This is the stack trace i get:

```
at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at ReachPhoneApp.CacheReader.GetPlayerFromCache(String gamertagIn)
   at ReachPhoneApp.Page2.GetPlayerData()
   at ReachPhoneApp.Page2.cacheWriter_UpdateComplete()
   at ReachPhoneApp.CacheWriter.WritePlayerDataToCache(String fileNameIn, Object objectIn)
   at ReachPhoneApp.CacheWriter.client_GetGameHistoryCompleted(Object sender, GetGameHistoryCompletedEventArgs e)
   at ReachPhoneApp.ReachAPI.ReachApiSoapClient.OnGetGameHistoryCompleted(Object state)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Comment: What is the value of gamerTagIn when it fails?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, this class is only called once and that is the only time it fails.  I'm 99% sure it's a problem with only the class.

Comment: I haven't added anything for that yet JP, but i've used debug to clarify the file exists and the username is the same as that being input. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Okay so i was wrong the second time and right the first; the class IS called once before, and it works, but on second call it fails. 

I'm guessing it has something to do with the file not being closed properly? I assumed the 'using' clause would handle all of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that you don't somehow have two threads accessing IsolatedStorage at the same time (ie. in VS Debug.View.Threads and verify that at the time of the exception you don't have multiple paths through the same IsoStore code).

This happened in my WP7 code once every few days and was tricky to find, as it seemed to occur only when not connectected to the debugger.

Comment: I was unable to confirm this as the API i was developing around has since been closed and I am unable to complete the project. As it has the highest amount of votes I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Is there something you can do so that even when two threads are accessing `IsolatedStorage` at the same time, the exception isn't thrown?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call:

```
stream.Close();
```

before

```
return loadedPlayer;
```

Comment: That hasn't fixed it. I tried putting that into all the other methods which access the cache as well. I'm going to ask my teacher about it this week and see if he has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you didn't specify that multiple threads could read/write at the same time by specifying a System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite or whatever access you need as the last parameter of OpenFile.

[See the discussion here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/100640/598888.aspx#598888) on the Microsoft Forums.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this in the next couple of days. I haven't touched this project after I got stuck on this error because no one had the answer.

Comment: A MILLION UPBOATS. I think you just fixed a concurrency issue in SterlingDB. :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well, but for completely different reasons as mentioned above. I hadn't created the directory that I was saving into.

```cs
private void SaveStringDataToStorage(string sDirectory, string sFileName, string sFileContent)
    {
        string sPath;
        //            
        using (IsolatedStorageFile oFile = solatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!oFile.DirectoryExists(sDirectory))
                oFile.CreateDirectory(sDirectory);
            //
            sPath = Path.Combine(sDirectory, sFileName);
            //
            using (var oWriter = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(sPath, FileMode.Create, oFile)))
                oWriter.Write(sFileContent);
        }
    }
```

Using this code will work if you had the same problem as me, plus it's pretty simple so you can adapt it to whatever you need. I was using this code before I had issues, but I'd forgotten the `!` so the directory was never created haha. Just typical. Hope this helps :)

EDIT

Looking closer at the original question, it may be that the file didn't exist. I think it's always best to do `IsolatedStorageFile.DirectoryExists()` and `IsolatedStorageFile.FileExists()` before trying to access either location, whether you are reading or writing.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you use `IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile("filename", FileMode.Open)` your file gets locked by this thread and no other thread would be able to access this file until 1st thread close it. But if you like to share your file in multiple threads for read purpose only then I would recommend you to use following override

`IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile("filename", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)`

see details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190169%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)